# Convert Normal water to cool instantly

Tags: fluid-dynamics, physical-chemistry, superfluidity, cold-fusion

Is it possible to convert the hot/normal water to cold steam instantly(may be within 1/2hr) without using refrigerators etc. If yes, how far can the cold steam travel. I am not sure with all the fluid mechanic concepts, but a curious question in mind. For instance, If I have a 1000ltr tank of moderate water and I need to convert it to cold water which generates cold fumes/steam and pass that steam at 10m distance. Not specific to physics but, chemical related solutions are also appreciated.
Thanks in advance.